# Get current post id witout passing in shortcode

Tags: shortcode

Is that possible to get current post ID without passing in shortcode as parameter. Like [related-post] I want to get the post ID in which post this shortcode will use.

```
add_shortcode( 'related-article', 'related_article_title' );
function related_article_title( $atts ) {
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    echo $post_id; 
    ob_start();
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'order' => 'DESC',
        )
    );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {   ?>
    <div class="menu-row">
        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
            Leggi anche: <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php $myvariable = ob_get_clean();
    return $myvariable;
}
}
```

Comment: What does `get_the_ID()` returns? You can always find current  post ID on global $post_id

Comment: get_the_ID() return nothing here but global $post; $post_id = $post->ID; work for me.

Answer (score 6):

```
add_shortcode( 'related-article', 'related_article_title' );
function related_article_title( $atts ) {
    global $post;
    echo $post->ID; // currently viewing post id
    ob_start();
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'order' => 'DESC',
        )
    );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {   ?>
    <div class="menu-row">
        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
            Leggi anche: <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php $myvariable = ob_get_clean();
    return $myvariable;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just as @gorakh-shrestha was trying, using `global $post` and then `$post->ID`, is a good way to proceed, even inside a shortcode

Comment: Hi i am passing ajax callback to shortcode. And i want to get page id of current page on which shortcode is used. But i am not able to get the page id using global $post->ID;

Comment: This is not a forum, it's just a place where you should comment the answer given. For that issue, don't be afraid to open up a new Question, after searching for already given answers, of course :-)

Comment: I have done with my issue.Thanks :)